# PEAR DB, moving from MySQL 4 to 5, .ini file issue?

Tags: php, mysql, pear, ini

We're running a custom made CMS that uses PEAR DB class to handle the database. The database is using MySQL 4.0. Our hosting provider is updating to MySQL 5.0 and deactivating all databases using 4.0. I've exported the old DB and made a new 5.0 one (I recommend [`bigdump.php`](http://www.ozerov.de/bigdump/) for this, we had around 500k lines).

The migration was mostly successful, but there's been some side effects (some pages are missing content that was there earlier, which ones affected seems random). PEAR relies on some sort of .ini files that act as maps of the DB. I didn't code the system so I'm not familiar with how this works. I just copied the old .ini files but I have a feeling I need to somehow generate new ones. [The manual](http://pear.php.net/manual/en/package.database.db-dataobject.intro-autobuilding.php) describes a `createTables.php` but running this does nothing, the script crashes with no output.

The ini file looks a bit like this:

```
[artist]
id = 129
first_name = 2
last_name = 130
display_name = 130
bio = 66
is_live = 145
is_deleted = 145
date_updated = 384

[artist__keys]
id = N

[artist_image]
artist_id = 129
url = 130
date_updated = 384

and so on for all DB tables...
```

I understand that this issue is very specific and it's hard to help, but if someone could point me in the right direction that'd be much appreciated. Thanks.

Answer (score 0):

This is not the DB package itself but [DB_DataObject](http://pear.php.net/DB_DataObject). It's an early object-relational mapper (ORM) and still works with today's MySQL.

Comment: Thanks. We're running the same custom CMS on other sites with MySQL 5 without problems. Do you have any clues about the .ini file generator?